# Open source conversion of shapefile to ArcGIS Server JSON

Tags: arcgis-server, geojson, ogr2ogr

Are there any open source command-line or python tools available to convert a shapefile (or other esri datasource) to ArcGIS Server JSON?

I'd like something that emulates the ArcGIS [Features to JSON](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/features-to-json.htm) tool.

Alternatively, a tool to convert standard GeoJSON to ArcGIS Server JSON would also work, but I haven't been able to find one of those either.

My ultimate goal is to convert a shapefile to ArcGIS Server geojson, then `POST` that to an ArcGIS Service endpoint.

Comment: ogr2ogr tool http://blog.adamw523.com/shapefile-to-geojson/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That command `ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4269 -f geoJSON Neighbourhoods.json Neighbourhoods.shp` converts the shapefile to vanilla GeoJSON, correct? I'm looking for something to convert to ArcGIS Server GeoJSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GeoJSON format and the ArcGIS Server JSON format ([ArcGIS Server REST API:geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/REST/APIREF/index.html?geometry.html)) are simple Python dictionaries

There are many Python spatial modules which have the [Geo_interface protocol (GeoJSON like)](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756)([list of modules with examples](https://github.com/mlaloux/Python-geo_interface-applications)).

For example with [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html)

```py
import fiona
lines = fiona.open("a_shapefile.shp")
# first feature of the shapefile
line = lines.next()
print line 
{'geometry': {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [(-97.06138, 32.837), (-97.06133, 32.836), (-97.06124, 32.834), (-97.06127, 32.832)]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'FID', 0), (u'long', 103.73)])}
geom = line['geometry']
print geom
{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [(-97.06138, 32.837), (-97.06133, 32.836), (-97.06124, 32.834), (-97.06127, 32.832)]}
```

Transform to ArcGIS Server JSON format (dictionary to other dictionary)

```py
arc = {"paths" : [ geom['coordinates']],"spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326}}
print arc
{'paths': [[(-97.06138, 32.837), (-97.06133, 32.836), (-97.06124, 32.834), (-97.06127, 32.832)]], 'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}}
```

Compare with the the 2D polyline in [ArcGIS Server REST API:geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/REST/APIREF/index.html?geometry.html)

Transform to JSON

```py
import json
json.dumps(res)
'{"paths": [[[-97.06138, 32.837], [-97.06133, 32.836], [-97.06124, 32.834], [-97.06127, 32.832]]], "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326}}'
```

You can do the same things with other geometries.

The only problem is the "wkid" value (I dont'know ArcGIS). With Fiona, for example

```py
lines.crs
{'init': u'epsg:4326'}
```

#### New

> esri JSON handles inner rings differently, and requires the first and last point of the polygon to be the same.

It is not specific to ESRI but for all polygons:

Using [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#linearrings)

```py
 from shapely.geometry.polygon import LinearRing
 # linearRing of a Polygon with 3 points 
 ring = LinearRing([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
 poly = Polygon(list(ring.coords))
 print poly
 POLYGON ((0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
 # Polygon with 4 points and first and last point equal
 from shapely.geometry import mapping # geo_interface
 mapping(Polygon(list(ring.coords)))
 {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)),)}
```

Therefore, If I use the first polygon in [ArcGIS Server REST API:geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/REST/APIREF/index.html?geometry.html)

```py
ring = {'rings': [[[-97.06138, 32.837], [-97.06133, 32.836], [-97.06124, 32.834], [-97.06127, 32.832], [-97.06138, 32.837]], [[-97.06326, 32.759], [-97.06298, 32.755], [-97.06153, 32.749], [-97.06326, 32.759]]], 'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}}
shapely_ring =  LinearRing(ring['rings'][0])
mapping(shapely_ring)
{'type': 'LinearRing', 'coordinates': ((-97.06138, 32.837), (-97.06133, 32.836), (-97.06124, 32.834), (-97.06127, 32.832), (-97.06138, 32.837))}
mapping(Polygon(list(shapely_ring.coords)))
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((-97.06138, 32.837), (-97.06133, 32.836), (-97.06124, 32.834), (-97.06127, 32.832), (-97.06138, 32.837)),)}
```

> > > 

Comment: Thanks for your response! Fiona is a great tool to programmatically access the coordinates of each polygon, but unfortunately I don't think esri JSON is that similar to the way these coordinates are listed. Per [this strangely formatted slide deck](http://calvinmetcalf.github.io/esri2open), esri JSON handles inner rings differently, and requires the first and last point of the polygon to be the same.

Comment: Given all these uncertainties, I'm looking for a tested script/utility, rather than hack together my own.

Comment: look above in new

Comment: Thanks for adding this @gene. I imagine I'll run into some additional unforeseen gotchas with the differences in ArcGIS Server json and GeoJSON, but this gives me a good start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Esri has some JavaScript libraries that will get you from GeoJSON to ArcGIS Server JSON.

- [Terraformer ArcGIS Parser](http://terraformer.io/arcgis-parser/)
- [arcgis-to-geojson-utils](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-to-geojson-utils) (Despite the name, it converts in both directions)

Comment: Thanks @Jeff! I imagine this is the preferred option from a technical standpoint, but given my unfamiliarity with JavaScript/Node it presents a bit of a challenge. I'll try it out and see what I can do. Thanks!